# Connector which could derive the topic name

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I am using confluent 6.2.0

I have one microservice which results data in the below structure

```
micro-service/
   date/
     hour/
       entity1.txt
       entity2.txt
       ...
       entity100.txt
       ...
```

Processing speed is 10-500ms based on the number of entities. If event1 has entity1, entity10, then the respective entity files would be updated in the respective processing hour.

**Goal:** Once these files are processed, have to move the hourly data to hive.

**Plan:** Spool Dir Source Connector -> Kafka -> Hdfs3 Sink Connector -> Hive partitioned parque file

**Problem**

I have to create hundreds of spool dir connector as schema is different on each entity file. I need schema because I am using `ExtractTopic$value` transformation to derive the topic name.

Is there any connector which could derive the topic name from fileName/SomeOtherWay to move it to kafka with single instance of connector with multiple task threads.

I could have 100 source connector if it is only one microservice but which would add more maintenance problem as there are many micro-services where each one have many entities.

Comment: If each file has a different format, I don't think Kafka Connect is a valid solution, at least, not trying to glob the whole folder... You might want to look into Logstash instead with its filter plugins that can better manipulate messages. Or are these CSV/JSON files that you can read line-by-line and parse later when messages are already in Kafka?

Comment: @OneCricketeer my use case is that I have the parsed data in those files. One file belongs to one hive table. To avoid small file issue in hdfs, we have this hourly aggregation. And instead of having many consolidators, thought of having connectors per microservice.

Comment: Can each of those services write to Kafka instead of files? All I'm saying is that Connect probably isn't the most ideal tool here. If using Hive, Spark or Flink would be more suited

Comment: Yes. I would give you more details. Each one is currently flume aggregation from Kafka. Changing this to Kafka streams to avoid back pressure which causes more duplicates in hive. So kakfa streams processes the data and writes to file. It can write to Kafka as well. Producing in a file would be faster than producing to Kafka. I imagine that Kafka would be 3times slower as it has to replicate to 3 modes if RF is 3. Have you ever encountered duplicates in Kafka streams? Really thanks for your help

Comment: Spark and flink also do require extra computation cluster. Kafka streams doesn't as data already in Kafka. Please provide your opinions on this.

Comment: @OneCricketeer please suggest from your experience.

Comment: Kafka Streams doesn't duplicate data in my experience. It consumes, and it produces, just like normal. The problem with having it write to files (at least in all the environments that I've ran it) is that we use containers which can die/move at any time from the scheduler, and don't actual have access to the host's disk. Using Streams to _produce_ to topics, which then get read by Kafka _Connect, Spark, or now Flink_ are what other teams are doing to work around that problem. And you don't wait for 3 replicas for each write, only `min.insync.isr`, if you want to ensure the data is available